# How to add cmake definitions for a dependency target?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I have an executable A that links to a dynamic library dependency B. All is compiling and linking correctly but now I want to set a cmake definition for the B dependency inside my CMakeLists.txt, how can I do it?

To resume, now I have to do this everytime:

```
cmake -DBLIBRARY_BUILD_TESTS=0 .
```

I want to put that -DBLIBRARY_BUILD_TESTS=0 inside my CMakeLists.txt to always configure the B dependency with that flag set to 0, to do this:

```
cmake .
```

Comment: My question is not how to add a compile definition, but instead a cmake definition. Maybe I'm wrong with the "definition" term, maybe it's a cmake variable?

Comment: `set(LIBRARY_BUILD_TESTS 0)`

Comment: I would add this as a cmake option with the default to ON. That way in cmake-gui the user can change the default if they want, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/option.html

Comment: Ok, Cinder Biscuits is right.. >_<. Make an answer and get the reward for the stupid question!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define CMake variables, you need to `SET` them like so:

```
SET(LIBRARY_BUILD_TESTS 0)
```

or if boolean:

```
SET(LIBRARY_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
```

If this is something that should be user configurable, use an `OPTION`:

```
OPTION(LIBRARY_BUILD_TESTS "Build library tests" OFF)
```